# Access map.directionsRenderers[0].directions.routes[0].overview_path.

Tags: angularjs, ng-map

I am using angular JS and ng-map.
Is it possible to get distance by using
map.directionsRenderers[0].directions.routes[0].overview_path

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can used this code to get your distances.

```
<p>APPROX DISTANCES: {{map.directionsRenderers[0].directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text}}</p>
```

to know more here is the link:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I got this solution few month back. It was my responsibilities to post it here...
But you already have done it ... Thank You Mr. Albert :) 
Anyway is it possible to calculate map distance without showing the Map ??

Comment: yes you can. check in the console.log. here is the code:

Comment: `var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var request = {
      origin: {lat: , lng: },//add latitude and longitude here
      destination: {lat: , lng: },//add latitude and longitude here
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        console.log(result); //you can calculate here
      }
    });`